# MySQL divide two series by eachother

Tags: mysql

I have several data series in a MySQL table.

The fields are Series, Date, Value.  Is there a way for me to select, for two distinct Series,  all the dates for which the series overlap and then for each date, the quotient of the value from series one and series two.

Example:

`Series Date Value

 Dogs    2004 10

 Dogs    2005 12

 Dogs    2006 14

 Dogs    2007 16

 Cats    2004 6

 Cats    2005 6

 Cats    2006 7

 Cats    2007 4`

I would like something like `SELECT Cats/Dogs` and get the following result

`Date Value

2004 .6

2005 .5

2006 .5

2007 .25`

Comment: Please provide examples and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a self-join on your table.

```
SELECT cats.Series, cats.value / dogs.value 
FROM animals cats
INNER JOIN animals dogs 
        ON dogs.Date = cats.Date
WHERE cats.Series = "Cats"
AND dogs.Series = "Dogs"
```

It would be preferable for performance to have an index on `Date`, and a key on `(Series,Date)` would be ideal.